# Apollo Client: best practice to initialize cache with default values?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, state-management, react-state-management, apollo-cache-inmemory

I've searched for a lot of tutorials about local state management with Apollo Client.

To initialize the cache with some init values, from this [example](https://github.com/apollographql/ac3-state-management-examples/blob/master/apollo-local-state/src/cache.tsx), I can do it with `typePolicies`. By defining reactive variables like this:

```
const todosInitialValue = ...
export const todosVar: ReactiveVar<Todos> = makeVar<Todos>(
  todosInitialValue
);
```

Also, I've seen tutorials initializing by `cache.writeData({  data: initialState });` after the client is created.

I would love to know the difference, and which one is preferred.